# I am not able to install peewee using pycharm terminal. I am using this 'pip install peewee' but can't import the library

Tags: python, installation, peewee

Command "C:\Users\asus\Anaconda2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-54ytkq\peewee\setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\asus\appd
ata\local\temp\pip-q5dadg-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\pip-
build-54ytkq\peewee\

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

It solved actually because microsoft visual c++ for python needs to be installed in my computer
after inatlling that it worked properly